# Solo en ciertos dispositivos no funciona

Tags: java, android

Buenos días, estoy desarrollando una app con mapas, y todo funciona bien, sin embargo, en un dispostivo `LG xMax` **no funcionan los mapas**, aparece el mensaje de que la aplicación se ha detenido. Sólo en ese dispositivo. 
Esto es lo que aparece en el log:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: 
  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2440)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2500)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:163)
  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1362)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5585)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method:0)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:730)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:620)
Caused by: android.view.InflateException: 
  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:539)
  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423)
  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374)
  at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:409)
  at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:2171)
  at parroquia.sanjosedeavalos.MapasTemplos.onCreate(MapasTemplos.java:21)
  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6279)
  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1108)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2393)
```

Comment: Puede ser la versión de android que ejecuta el dispositivo, compruebalo agrega los detalles a la pregunta

Comment: tuve  un problema similar, y no es tanto culpa del dispositivo, si no de la versión de android que este utilice. usualmente en qué API corres tu app, y que API tiene el teléfono en cuestión?

Comment: En API 21. El detalle esta en que antes de firmarla, si funcioban los mapas en ese telefono, pero luego de firmarla, dejo de funcionar. Sin embargo,en otros dispositivos si funciona. ¿Pueden ser los google Play services del dispositivo LG?

Comment: has habilitado `Proguard` en la versión release ? me refiero a `minifyEnabled true` en tu archivo build.gradle

Comment: No, eso no lo he realizado, está en 'false'

Comment: Lo solucione con la linea `android:hardwareAccelerated="true"`